# Running Multiple Queries from an Excel Sheet in VBScript

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, odbc, sap-ase

Hello Scripters from all over, I am currently working on a VBScript to pull Query parameters from an excel sheet and run a Query on an SQL server *(Sybase ASE)* for each line in the excel sheet.

Currently I have the code that pulls the parameters successfully and runs the first row, but when I begin the next row, the query fails due to "Missing Object", but I have already attempted to keep the ADO Connection open and rerunning a query into the recordset, as well as re-creating the connection for every row in the excel sheet and running the recordset. My code currently is as follows:

```vb
Dim MyConnection, MyRecordSet, MyExcel, MyExcelBook, MyExcelSheet
Dim ConnectionString, Parameter1, Parameter2, SQL, I
ConnectionString = "Driver=ODBC Driver;UserID=Admin;Password=Pass;"

Set MyExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set MyExcelBook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Test.xls")
Set MyExcelSheet = MyExcelBook.WorkSheets(2)
Set MyConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set MyRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
MyConnection.Open ConnectionString
I = 2

Do while MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,2).Value <> ""
    Parameter1 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,6).Value
    Parameter2 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,7).Value
    SQL = "Select * From Table Where Type=" & Parameter1 & " AND Color=" & Parameter2 & ";"
    MyRecordSet.Open SQL, MyConnection
    'Save RecordSet to another Excel sheet'
    MyRecordSet.Close
    I = I + 1
loop

MyConnection.Close
Set MyConnection = Nothing
```

Is there any way to run another query on the same connection to the database without running into the

> Object Required

error?

---

Edit after [suggested changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005518/running-multiple-queries-from-an-excel-sheet-in-vbscript#comment71193334_42006204), still have the same error.

```vb
Dim MyConnection, MyExcel, MyExcelBook, MyExcelSheet
Dim ConnectionString, Parameter1, Parameter2, SQL, I
ConnectionString = "Driver=ODBC Driver;UserID=Admin;Password=Pass;"

Set MyExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set MyExcelBook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Test.xls")
Set MyExcelSheet = MyExcelBook.WorkSheets(2)
Set MyConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
MyConnection.Open ConnectionString
I = 2

Do while MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,2).Value <> ""
    Parameter1 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,6).Value
    Parameter2 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,7).Value
    SQL = "Select * From Table Where Type=" & Parameter1 & " AND Color=" & Parameter2 & ";"
    Dim MyRecordSet
    Set MyRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    MyRecordSet.Open SQL, MyConnection
    'Save RecordSet to another Excel sheet'
    MyRecordSet.Close
    I = I + 1
loop

MyConnection.Close
Set MyConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `SQL` variable contains the expected query on successive iterations of the loop? Use `WScript.Echo SQL` to see what each query contains, I'd hazard a guess to the problem being the parameters passed from Excel.

Comment: I have Echoed the SQL , and they both are correct on 2 different iterations. I attempted to reconnect the ADODB.Connection in the do...while loop and found that the error occurred there as well. So my assumpttion is that its not necessarily the Recordset that's causing the error, but MyConnection on the 2nd iteration.

Comment: Ok, what about version of SQL Server you are using? Try using the correct SQL Server instead of the generic ODBC Driver, see http://connectionstrings.com/sqlserver/

Comment: In this script, I used the generic driver for reference only, Currently I'm connected to a Sybase ASE ODBC Driver and double-checked the connection string. It is correct, otherwise I would not be able to get the first query to work.

Comment: Well, I can't see anything *inherently* wrong with the code, which suggests it's the provider causing the problem, there is some [interesting information here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35906317/692942) about a similar issue, maybe it will help? Would need more detailed information about the error to help much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much testing of different ideas, I finally got the code to work. The issue happened when MyRecordSet was being closed. The status went back to 0 and when you attempted to re-open MyRecordSet, it would fail with a broken object. Reconnecting an then re-opening MyRecordSet led to the same error. So here is the finished code edit that works.

```
Dim MyConnection, MyRecordSet, MyExcel, MyExcelBook, MyExcelSheet
Dim ConnectionString, Parameter1, Parameter2, SQL, I
ConnectionString = "Driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;UserID=Admin;Password=Pass;Pooling=False"

Set MyExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set MyExcelBook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Test.xls")
Set MyExcelSheet = MyExcelBook.WorkSheets(2)
I = 2

Do while MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,2).Value <> ""
    Parameter1 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,6).Value
    Parameter2 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,7).Value
    SQL = "Select * From Table Where Type=" & Parameter1 & " AND Color=" & Parameter2 & ";"
    Set MyConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    MyConnection.Open ConnectionString
    Set MyRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    MyRecordSet.Open SQL, MyConnection
    'Save RecordSet to another Excel sheet'
    Set MyRecordSet = Nothing
    Set MyConnection = Nothing
    I = I + 1
loop
```

Now if you ask me if its Database specific, I would not know. But this code works with using the Adaptive Server Enterprise Driver and I did use LankyMart's advice with turning connection pooling off. I understand only setting the 'object = nothing' without closing the connection first goes against standard coding practices, but it works. Thanks to those that helped out.

Answer (score 0):

The connection object doesn't need to be opened and closed for every query. Try it this way:

```
Dim MyConnection, MyExcel, MyExcelBook, MyExcelSheet
Dim ConnectionString, Parameter1, Parameter2, SQL, I
ConnectionString = "Driver=ODBC Driver;UserID=Admin;Password=Pass;"

Set MyExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set MyExcelBook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Test.xls")
Set MyExcelSheet = MyExcelBook.WorkSheets(2)
I = 2

Set MyConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
MyConnection.Open ConnectionString
Do while MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,2) <> ""
    Parameter1 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,6).Value
    Parameter2 = MyExcelSheet.Cells(I,7).Value
    SQL = "Select * From Table Where Type=" & Parameter1 & " AND Color=" & Parameter2 & ";"
    Dim MyRecordSet
    Set MyRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    MyRecordSet.Open SQL, MyConnection
    'Save RecordSet to another Excel sheet'
    MyRecordSet.Close
    Set MyRecordSet = Nothing
    I = I + 1
Loop
MyConnection.Close
Set MyConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: I just tried running that and it still runs into the "Object Required" runtime error. The connection is still open, but it fails when recreating the recordset object

Comment: Try the above revision, where I placed the `Dim MyRecordSet` inside of the loop.

Comment: I then Run into an 'Object Redefined' compilation error. I would edit my comment earlier to state that its when using MyConnection.open instead of creating the object.

Comment: Did you remove the `Dim MyRecordSet` from the top? Also, the `MyConnection` should not be in the loop. So the error is happening before the loop?

Comment: Sorry about that, working on another project at the same time. But the error occurs at MyRecordset.Open in the do...while loop. I also did not remove the Dim MyRecordSet at the top, but when I do, I run into the 'Object Required' error again.

Comment: Will you update your question and add on your current code?

Comment: Thank you. Please move, Set MyRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") and Dim MyRecordSet into the do while loop, before you have the .Open command.

Comment: I have moved them into the do...while loop and the error still occurs. I have also attempted 'MyRecordSet = MyConnection.Execute SQL' as an alternative for MyRecordSet and it again fails with the object required. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think you'll have to troubleshoot this on your own more for any progress to really be made. Your script stating 'Object Required' determines that whatever broken object halting your script is empty, not populated, I was trying to display that your RecordSet needs to be refreshed per loop. But it appears more than that is occuring. There may be conflicting variables or other things affiliated to the code that are not shown. Best of luck.

Comment: None of what you have suggested there will make any difference and is nothing the OP hasn't already mentioned.

Comment: That's because I told him to update his question and code. If you have further suggestions, submit an answer.

Comment: Like I said the updates you suggested make no difference. For starters the OP wasn't opening and closing the connection for every query.

Comment: Then. Suggest. An. Answer.

Comment: There is not enough information to suggest an answer.